# How do I stop Lubuntu displaying Firefox on desktop 3?

Tags: lubuntu, configuration

I have managed to set Firefox so that it only opens on desktop 3. I can move it to other desktops, but I'd like to set it up so that it opens on whatever desktop I'm on.

I did this (I think) by right clicking on the titlebar, selecting 'Send to desktop' and selecting desktop 3.

I have checked ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-RC.xml but this has not been modified. Googling for an answer only seems to bring up ways to make a specific app open on a specific desktop, not how to stop it.

I am using Lubuntu 18.04.

Many thanks, in advance,
David

Comment: Right click the title bar and select `Always on Visible Workspace`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, I don't seem to have that option. I have selected Send to desktop > All desktops, but it still insists on opening on desktop 3. I've just tried a sudo apt purge firefox and reinstall, but even that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Sorry about the Always on Visible, that is Xubuntu's settings.  That is odd!  I logged into my Lubuntu installation and the Firefox stays always visible on all the desktops when I choose All Desktops.  I am thinking there is a possibility of the lxsession storing a session that has it set to open Firefox on Desktop 3.  Not 100% sure though.  https://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXSession might have something helpful.

Comment: Progress! I couldn't find anything in lxsession, but it gave me a few ideas and, eventually, I ended up renaming my ~/.mozilla/ folder, forcing firefox to recreate my profile and - hey presto! - FF now opens where I want it to. Now all I need to do is try and track down what exactly the difference is. Thanks for your help.